# Statistics help: Conditional variance understanding of a die problem

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, variance

I'm having difficulty understanding a solution to a given problem that I tried to solve.

**Problem**: Suppose n fair dice are rolled. Those that show a six are
rolled again. What are the mean and the variance of the number of sixes
obtained in the second round of this experiment?

**Solution**: Suppose Y is the number of dice in the first round that show
a six

Let X be the number of dice in the second round that show a
six

Given: $$Y = y$$
$$X ∼ Bin(y, \frac{1}{6})$$
$$Also, \ Y ∼ Bin(n, \frac{1}{6})$$
$$\therefore E(X) = E[E(X|Y = y)] = E_{Y}[\frac{y}{6}]=\frac{n}{36}$$

Note: I got this part above.

My problem understanding starts here:

$$Var(X) = E_{Y}[Var(X|Y = y)] + Var_{Y}[E(X|Y = y)]$$
$$= E_{Y}[y\frac{1}{6}\frac{5}{6}] + Var_{Y}[\frac{y}{6}]$$
$$= \frac{5}{36}\frac{n}{6} + \frac{1}{36}n\frac{1}{6}\frac{5}{6}$$
$$= \frac{35n}{1296}$$

My question: How does $E_{Y}[Var(X|Y = y)] $ become $E_{Y}[y\frac{1}{6}\frac{5}{6}]$ ? I basically need an explanation.

I'm having difficulty understanding conditional variances so any help in terms of tips or resources to understand it better would be great. Thank you.

Comment: What does $y\frac 16\frac 56$ mean?  Do you mean the product?  If so, that is truly bad notation.

Comment: It is the product. Solution written as I found it , taken from a document by Prof. Michael Levine. Reference: https://www.stat.purdue.edu/~mlevins/docs/stat516/lecture_notes/iter_exp.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $X|Y=y\sim \textrm{Bin}(n=y,p=1/6)$ therefore
$$\textrm{Var}[X|Y=y]=np(1-p)=y\frac{1}{6}\frac{5}{6}$$
This is because if we know the number of sixes of the first round (i.e. $y$) then we know how many dice will be rolled in the second round.

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that I made a stupid mistake which prompted the question (which now looks silly).